# Failed to use <picture> and <source> element to switch pictures

Tags: html

Trying to learn some basic HTML here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

I wrote a simple HTML file that should switch pictures for different screen width, it is almost the same as the example in the article, but it doesn't work, what went wrong?

This is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    body {
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur libero nibh, convallis nec mattis in, varius sed turpis. Fusce dapibus purus sapien, ut maximus tortor dictum a. Praesent venenatis pharetra placerat. Cras eu aliquam augue. Nullam id luctus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce faucibus lectus sed magna euismod tempor. Aliquam sed consequat sapien, in finibus lorem. Suspendisse cursus ultrices dolor id dictum. Proin cursus nisi scelerisque, molestie lacus vel, imperdiet odio. Curabitur at augue gravida metus consequat congue. Quisque sed orci accumsan erat iaculis feugiat. Sed ornare mi id est fringilla sodales. Quisque enim leo, ornare vitae sapien eu, blandit dignissim sapien. Maecenas venenatis pretium vestibulum. </p>
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="Vanessa Vailatti Portrait.png">
        <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="Vanessa Vailatti.png">
        <img src="Vanessa Vailatti.png" alt="Vanessa Vailatti standing by the lake">
    </picture>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images names cannot be displayed with spaces either name needs to be saved with "-" or "_" or "with out space between two words". Check with by changing image names in your code. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Actually, images of space separated names can be displayed but they don't switch.

Answer (score 0):

"Vanessa Vailatti.png" this shape can not be png. "vanessa-vailatti.png" should be like this.